# How do I find out if my MacBook Pro supports virtual extensions?

Tags: virtualization

I am curious to know if it's possible to use my MacBook Pro as virtual host to test application in different OS environments. I guess it would improve performance of applications running on virtual OS .

Comment: I'm pretty sure all Macs support virtualization and don't require any configuration to do so.

Comment: Does Mac support kernel based virtual machines ?

Comment: Can't cite an "official" answer, but seeing as I can virtualize a whole lot using Parallels Desktop on my MacBook Air with decent performance, it *has* to have hardware or firmware support.  The days of viable pure-software virtualization are far behind us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, All recent Macs support virtualization.

Apple released native hypervisor functionality with their OS X Yosemite release, their Hypervisor.framework.

What this does is it allows you to run a VM natively on OS X, without the need for client hypervisor (such as VMware Fusion or VirtualBox).

[Source](http://technodrone.blogspot.com/2016/01/native-mac-osx-virtualization-with.html)

Comment: I will give it a try to veertu

Comment: Could you please add relevant sections from your source to the body if possible? It makes it easier to read and provides security in case the link dies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As per @JMY1000 's comment, please provide at least a brief summary of the Source. Over time links break and then anyone else looking at your answer will be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of Intel processor extensions that indicate easy virtualization (VMX / APIC) - but anyone could write a virtualization engine on code alone with enough smarts, budget, engineering so just because a specific extension is lacking, you can't virtualize.

That being said - you'll be hard pressed to find a Mac running OS X (now macOS) that doesn't have VMX or better:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization

  `sysctl machdep.cpu.features`